# Printing 2D Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

When I try to print 2D `ArrayList`, the output looks like this:

```
A B CD E FG H I
```

instead of:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

In the constructor  `public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem)`, I copy the elements of the 2D `array` into the 2D `ArrayList`. Then, in `toString()` method, I loop throught the elements of the 2D `ArrayList` and output the result (but I can't get the desired result as I've mentioned above)

Class **Tester**

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] myString = {{"A B C"}, {"D E F"}, {"G H I"}};
        DenseBoard<String> temp1 = new DenseBoard<String>(myString, "a");
        System.out.println(temp1);
    }
}
```

Class **DenseBoard**

```
import java.util.*;
public class DenseBoard <T> {

    private T element;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard;

    public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem){
        this.myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
        this.element = fillElem;

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            ArrayList<T> values = new ArrayList<T>();
            for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
                values.add(x[i][j]);
            }
            myBoard.add(values);
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < myBoard.get(i).size(); j++){
                result += myBoard.get(i).get(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no place for a `println` within your toString method, since its use is to build a String, not to output anything to the standard output.
Change:

```
 public String toString(){
      String result = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < myBoard.get(i).size(); j++){
              result += myBoard.get(i).get(j);
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
      return result;
  }
```

to

```
 public String toString(){
      String result = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < myBoard.get(i).size(); j++){
              result += myBoard.get(i).get(j);
          }
          // System.out.println();
          result += "\n";
      }
      return result;
  }
```

As an aside, if this method is to be called frequently, consider using a StringBuilder.

Comment: Could you please explain why I cannot use `System.out.println()` for printing a new line in this code?

Comment: @Michael: why do you have a `toString` method? Not to output to console but to **build a String**. The println does not contribute to this in any way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `toString` method: you never add a line break there. Instead of you call `System.out.println();` which *prints* a line break.

```
public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < myBoard.get(i).size(); j++){
            result += myBoard.get(i).get(j);
        }
        result += System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return result;
}
```

[`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) returns the system-dependent line separator string.

Note that you should consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Your toString operation is printing out newlines, and then returning the string representation (which has none). Replace `System.out.println();` with `result += "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

First I added some logging....

```
import java.util.*;
public class DenseBoard <T> {
private T element;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard;

 public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem){
      this.myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
      this.element = fillElem;

      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
         ArrayList<T> values = new ArrayList<T>();
          for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
              T nextElement = x[i][j];
              System.err.println(String.format("adding x[%1$d][%2$d] (%3$s)", i, j, nextElement));
              values.add(x[i][j]);
          }
          System.err.println(String.format("added %1$d elements", values.size()));
          myBoard.add(values);
      }
  }
 public String toString(){
      String result = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < myBoard.get(i).size(); j++){
              result += myBoard.get(i).get(j);
          }
          // replaced the call to System.out.println() with "\n"..
          result+= "\n";

      }
      return result;
  }
}
```

After I ran a couple of times, it occurred to me that it was not a 2D array that was being passed as an argument to the constructor, so I tried this code to fix...

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args){

```
        String[][] myString = {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E", "F"}, {"G","H", "I"}};
        DenseBoard<String> temp1 = new DenseBoard<String>(myString, "a");
        System.out.println(temp1);
    }
}
```

Now the output I got...

```
$ java Tester
adding x[0][0] (A)
adding x[0][1] (B)
adding x[0][2] (C)
added 3 elements
adding x[1][0] (D)
adding x[1][1] (E)
adding x[1][2] (F)
added 3 elements
adding x[2][0] (G)
adding x[2][1] (H)
adding x[2][2] (I)
added 3 elements
ABC
DEF
GHI
```